# Concrete5 login with google

Tags: concrete5

I'm looking for documentation / tutorial on how to use the other authentication/login types. (C5.7) 
Don' t have access to a google app account to test.

- Do I need to create users first and enable other login types for those accounts?
- Does automatic registration also create a C5 account?
- Can I use groups and other permissions with any of this?

Context: School community with different locations (with own sub-site) each with different groups (and sub-site). They use Google Apps.

Comment: Project never went through.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to add each user account first if you enable automatic registration.

With automatic registration turned on in the verification types, the user will get a Concrete5 user account automatically when they first log in with their google credentails.
After the user account is created, anyone with the proper permissions can set the group for that user.

In your case, it will be difficult working with the automatic registration because of the different groups and permissions. You can only assign 1 group to the automatic registration process.

If each group has a different domainname in their e-mail address, I would setup automatic registration into a temporary group.
(For example: 'School A' people have *@schoola.com addresses)

Next, write a package that uses the on_user_add event (package controller - on_start method).
In the event you check the e-mail address of the added user and assign the appropriate group to the user. (in case the e-mail address check fails, you could send a mail to an administrator)

Here's more info on concrete5 events : https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/application-events/hooking-application-events
and a full list of events https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/appendix/full-event-list